# Jest: onChange event on a Dropdown does not change its value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `Dropdown` (`Multiselect` creates ultimately a `semantic-ui-react` `Dropdown`. Tests work all the same if I substitute `Multiselect` for `Dropdown`, its just more clear to have `Multiselect`) that is rendered within a `redux-form` and I am trying to select an option in `jest/enzyme`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Store is needed for ReduxFormWrapper because Redux Form uses it
    const middlewares = [thunk]
    const store = configureStore(middlewares)(STATE1)
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store} >
        <SavedVariants match={INIT_MATCH_PROPS} {...stateProps} {...dispatchProps} />
      </Provider>
    )
    //console.log(wrapper.debug())
})

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})

it('selects genes in the genes dropdown', () => {
    const newGenes = ['OR2M3']
    const genesDropdownBefore = wrapper.find('Multiselect').findWhere(n => n.prop('name') === 'genes').hostNodes()
    genesDropdownBefore.prop('onChange')('event', newGenes)
    expect(submitFormSearchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ "genes": newGenes })
    wrapper.update()
    const genesDropdownAfter = wrapper.find('Multiselect').findWhere(n => n.prop('name') === 'genes').hostNodes()
    console.log(genesDropdownAfter.instance().value)
})
```

I figured out that I can change `Dropdown` value like that:

```
genesDropdownBefore.instance().value = newGenes
```

But shouldn't `onChange` event update the value of the component? I suspect that maybe it is somehow related to internal management of its `state` by `redux-form`, but not sure. How to call a single `onChange` event and then verify the `Dropdown` value? Thats' what I am trying to test: that the value of the `Dropdown` was set correctly.

> Update

Printing out `Multiselect` `props()` I get the following:

```
  { error: false,
    meta:
     { active: false,
       asyncValidating: false,
       autofilled: false,
       dirty: true,
       dispatch: [Function],
       error: undefined,
       form: 'editSavedVariantTable',
       initial: [ 'OR2M3' ],
       warning: undefined,
       invalid: false,
       pristine: false,
       submitting: false,
       submitFailed: false,
       touched: false,
       valid: true,
       visited: false },
    onChange: [Function],
    name: 'genes',
    onBlur: [Function],
    onDragStart: [Function],
    onDrop: [Function],
    onFocus: [Function],
    value: '',
    label:
     { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
       type: { [Function: CustomLabel] propTypes: [Object] },
       key: 'geneSearchLabel',
       ref: null,
       props: { name: 'geneSearchLabel', style: [Object], text: 'Genes:' },
       _owner:
        FiberNode {
          tag: 1,
          key: null,
          elementType: [Function],
          type: [Function],
          stateNode: [BaseSavedVariants],
          return: [FiberNode],
          child: [FiberNode],
          sibling: null,
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: null,
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 1,
          nextEffect: null,
          firstEffect: [FiberNode],
          lastEffect: [FiberNode],
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: [FiberNode],
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 2824,
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: null,
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null },
       _store: {} },
    inline: true,
    options: [ { value: 'OR2M3', text: 'OR2M3' } ],
    placeholder: 'Select genes' }
```

The `value` is always empty and can't be set whatever I do. I think for that reason I am also getting a warning:

> Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`.

I tried `wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()`, then also made a function to update actual child component props:

```
  const changeProps = (wrapper, newProps) => {
      wrapper.setProps({
      children: (
        <SavedVariants
          {...newProps}
          match={INIT_MATCH_PROPS}
        />
      )
    })
  }
```

Which is working for hiding/showing the dropdown (its is done in the `render` function of the tested component) but is not working for changing its value through changing state.

For the selected option `Multiselect` creates a link `a.ui.label` which is absent when I try looking for it with `jest`, so it isn't rendered for some reason.

> Update

`wrapper.find('Multiselect').debug()` prints the following:

```
 <Multiselect error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select genes">
        <AddableSelect error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true}>
          <Select error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true}>
            <Memo() selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true}>
              <BaseSemanticInput selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} inputType="Dropdown" options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0">
                <FormDropdown selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" as={[Function: FormField]} control={[Function: Dropdown]}>
                  <FormField selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" control={[Function: Dropdown]}>
                    <div className="inline field">
                      <CustomLabel name="geneSearchLabel" style={{...}} text="Genes:" htmlFor={[undefined]}>
                        <div name="geneSearchLabel">
                          <label id="geneSearchLabel" style={{...}}>
                            Genes:
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </CustomLabel>
                      <Dropdown aria-describedby={{...}} aria-invalid={true} selection={true} fluid={true} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" placeholder="Select genes" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" content={[undefined]} disabled={[undefined]} required={[undefined]} type={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} additionLabel="Add " additionPosition="top" closeOnBlur={true} closeOnEscape={true} deburr={false} icon="dropdown" minCharacters={1} openOnFocus={true} searchInput="text" selectOnBlur={true} selectOnNavigation={true} wrapSelection={true}>
                        <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                          <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                            <div aria-describedby={{...}} aria-invalid={true} meta={{...}} name="genes" onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} content={[undefined]} required={[undefined]} type={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} role="combobox" aria-busy={[undefined]} aria-disabled={[undefined]} aria-expanded={false} className="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown" onBlur={[Function]} onClick={[Function]} onMouseDown={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} onChange={[Function]} tabIndex={[undefined]}>
                              <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                                <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                                  <DropdownSearchInput style={{...}} tabIndex="0" value="" type="text" onChange={[Function: onChange]} autoComplete="off">
                                    <input style={{...}} onChange={[Function]} aria-autocomplete="list" autoComplete="off" className="search" tabIndex="0" type="text" value="" />
                                  </DropdownSearchInput>
                                </RefFindNode>
                              </Ref>
                              <span className="sizer" />
                              <div className="default text" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic={true}>
                                Select genes
                              </div>
                              <Icon name="dropdown" className="" onClick={[Function: onClick]} as="i">
                                <i onClick={[Function]} aria-hidden="true" className="dropdown icon" />
                              </Icon>
                              <DropdownMenu aria-multiselectable={true} role="listbox" direction={[undefined]} open={[undefined]}>
                                <div aria-multiselectable={true} role="listbox" className="menu transition">
                                  <DropdownItem active={false} onClick={[Function]} selected={true} value="OR2M3" text="OR2M3" label={{...}} color={[undefined]} disabled={[undefined]} description={[undefined]} style={{...}}>
                                    <div color={[undefined]} style={{...}} role="option" aria-disabled={[undefined]} aria-checked={false} aria-selected={true} className="selected item" onClick={[Function]}>
                                      <span className="text">
                                        OR2M3
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </DropdownItem>
                                </div>
                              </DropdownMenu>
                            </div>
                          </RefFindNode>
                        </Ref>
                      </Dropdown>
                    </div>
                  </FormField>
                </FormDropdown>
              </BaseSemanticInput>
            </Memo()>
          </Select>
        </AddableSelect>
      </Multiselect>
      
      
      <Multiselect error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select families">
        <AddableSelect error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true}>
          <Select error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true}>
            <Memo() selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} options={{...}} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true}>
              <BaseSemanticInput selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={[Function]} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} inputType="Dropdown" options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0">
                <FormDropdown selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" as={[Function: FormField]} control={[Function: Dropdown]}>
                  <FormField selection={true} fluid={true} error={false} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" label={{...}} inline={true} placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" control={[Function: Dropdown]}>
                    <div className="inline field">
                      <CustomLabel name="familiesCustomLabel" checked={false} style={{...}} checkbox={true} checkboxLabel="only my families" text="Families:" onChange={[Function: mockConstructor]} htmlFor={[undefined]}>
                        <div name="familiesCustomLabel">
                          <label id="familiesCustomLabel" style={{...}}>
                            Families:
                          </label>
                          <Checkbox checked={false} onChange={[Function: mockConstructor]} htmlFor={[undefined]} inline="true" label="only my families" type="checkbox">
                            <div htmlFor={[undefined]} inline="true" className="ui checkbox" onClick={[Function]} onChange={[Function]} onMouseDown={[Function]} onMouseUp={[Function]}>
                              <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                                <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                                  <input checked={false} className="hidden" disabled={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} name={[undefined]} readOnly={true} tabIndex={0} type="checkbox" value={[undefined]} />
                                </RefFindNode>
                              </Ref>
                              <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                                <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                                  <label htmlFor={[undefined]}>
                                    only my families
                                  </label>
                                </RefFindNode>
                              </Ref>
                            </div>
                          </Checkbox>
                        </div>
                      </CustomLabel>
                      <Dropdown aria-describedby={{...}} aria-invalid={true} selection={true} fluid={true} meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="families" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" placeholder="Select families" renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" content={[undefined]} disabled={[undefined]} required={[undefined]} type={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} additionLabel="Add " additionPosition="top" closeOnBlur={true} closeOnEscape={true} deburr={false} icon="dropdown" minCharacters={1} openOnFocus={true} searchInput="text" selectOnBlur={true} selectOnNavigation={true} wrapSelection={true}>
                        <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                          <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                            <div aria-describedby={{...}} aria-invalid={true} meta={{...}} name="families" onDragStart={[Function]} onDrop={[Function]} content={[undefined]} required={[undefined]} type={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} role="combobox" aria-busy={[undefined]} aria-disabled={[undefined]} aria-expanded={false} className="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown" onBlur={[Function]} onClick={[Function]} onMouseDown={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} onChange={[Function]} tabIndex={[undefined]}>
                              <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                                <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
                                  <DropdownSearchInput style={{...}} tabIndex="0" value="" type="text" onChange={[Function: onChange]} autoComplete="off">
                                    <input style={{...}} onChange={[Function]} aria-autocomplete="list" autoComplete="off" className="search" tabIndex="0" type="text" value="" />
                                  </DropdownSearchInput>
                                </RefFindNode>
                              </Ref>
                              <span className="sizer" />
                              <div className="default text" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic={true}>
                                Select families
                              </div>
                              <Icon name="dropdown" className="" onClick={[Function: onClick]} as="i">
                                <i onClick={[Function]} aria-hidden="true" className="dropdown icon" />
                              </Icon>
                              <DropdownMenu aria-multiselectable={true} role="listbox" direction={[undefined]} open={[undefined]}>
                                <div aria-multiselectable={true} role="listbox" className="menu transition">
                                  <DropdownItem active={false} onClick={[Function]} selected={true} value="SF8313488_WES_CIDR" text="SF8313488_WES_CIDR" label={{...}} color={[undefined]} disabled={[undefined]} description={[undefined]} style={{...}}>
                                    <div color={[undefined]} style={{...}} role="option" aria-disabled={[undefined]} aria-checked={false} aria-selected={true} className="selected item" onClick={[Function]}>
                                      <span className="text">
                                        SF8313488_WES_CIDR
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </DropdownItem>
                                </div>
                              </DropdownMenu>
                            </div>
                          </RefFindNode>
                        </Ref>
                      </Dropdown>
                    </div>
                  </FormField>
                </FormDropdown>
              </BaseSemanticInput>
            </Memo()>
          </Select>
        </AddableSelect>
      </Multiselect>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue with react-select. You were almost there. The value is controlled internally, not by react-form but by semantic-ui. Sometimes `onChange` events doesn't update the value props.

But what you can try is to check the value in the component's html itself.If you check the developer tools, you can see that the value is available in  `<a class="ui label">`.

```
 it('selects genes in the genes dropdown', () => {
      const newGenes = ['OR2M3']
      const genesDropdownBefore = wrapper.find('Multiselect').findWhere(n => n.prop('name') === 'genes')
      genesDropdownBefore.prop('onChange')({ value: newGenes});
      wrapper.update()
      expect(submitFormSearchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ "genes": newGenes })
      expect(wrapper.find('Multiselect .ui.label').value).toEqual('OR2M3');
 })
```

Issues in your code were:

- `hostNodes()` will return the html of the component, not the react
  element. So you were calling props on the html structure rather than
  the component itself.
- The way you called the `onChange` is not correct. Refer my code above.
- There is no need to query the component again. `wrapper.update()` will give you the component with the latest changes.

Comment: `wrapper.find('Multiselect .ui.label').value` shows `undefined` somehow.

Comment: I updated the question to show what is printed when I use `console.log(wrapper.find('Multiselect').debug())`

Comment: Try logging something from the event handler. We will know from where the flow is breaking.